# Why owl carousel doesnt like doctype?

Tags: owl-carousel, doctype

I am working on a wordpress website developed by another developer.
When i met a requirement to add proper  (1st line, no empty lines, no other code before) to main document i noticed that owl carouse, that inits with following code, broke height:

```js
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        items: 1,
        pagination: true,
        navigation: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
    });
```

Saying breaks means two things. 1 - my owl carousel lives in a div that is a sibling of div with fixed height 600px; before fixing doctype owl carousel stretched to full heigth and worked fine. Now its height around 10-20% of full height; 
2 - in mobile mode it also not stretching but horizontally, in width.

Removing doctype from document - makes owl carouse work as expected, properly... that confuses me
I need doctype for other things and it's a good practive and a must have for any webpage to have

Why owl carousel doesnt like doctype ?

Comment: Magic of StackOverflow, 1.5 mins after i posted question i found one piece of solution - for mobile view. I had unproper background-position value in my css which was somewhy accepted when doctype not set, and after setting doctype it became invalid. Be sure to always use dimensions in bgp property - like : top 5px ( i had just 5)

Comment: And after 5 more mins or so - completly solved :)
So if someone met this kinda issue - when u fix doctype and got something broken in ur page - look for invalid css rules, that could be a long way :)
My complete solution was to fix css rule - background position and set .owl-carousel autoheight to false explicitly in init object, looks like its true by default, and i got all good and going